# Mocha + WebDriverIO - Common Functions

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I have a test which contains steps that I'll want to reuse in multiple files.

I'm thinking I could create a file called `common.js`, list all the functions in there and just call as and when I need.

Is this a recommended approach?

The only issue I feel is having a super long file of common methods and if i seperate then I'd need to use lots of `require` statements.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to do what you have hinted to make a `commonSpec.js` file and use it anywhere by `importTest()` which would be something like this :

**commonSpec.js**

```
describe('Common Steps that will be used by all', () => {
    it('Can log in', () => {
       //log in code
    });

    it('land on a particular page', () => {
        // assertion code for the particular page
    });
});
```

**commonSpecUsed.js**

```
describe("Common Specs", () => {
    importTest("common specs", './commonSpec.js');
});
```

The above approach is best and simple when they share the same specs and assert the same values. But when the assertions are different for e.g

- A normal user will land on a simple user page
- Registered user will land on their "my account" page
- Admin will land on their dashboard page ..etc..etc..

Then you might want to make your `commonSpec.js` file more dynamic by enabling it to accept parameters. This would be entirely based on your test requirements. Can be more helpful if you could please share some code snippet.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - how instead of the importTest - I'm going to use actual functions instead. Shouldn't make much of a difference should it?

Comment: Yah sure, you can do without importTest as well. Making your own functions and exporting them. The only difference here would be when you declare and export your own set of functions(common specs), you have liberty in doing so and can pass arguments to them as mentioned in the last paragraph of my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set up Page Objects, [as defined in the official docs](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/pageobjects.html). I also have [a video covering subject on YouTube](https://youtu.be/4_ZIaWhQ6Uk?t=1m10s).

If you don't want to do page objects, you can add custom commands to WebdriverIO using [the 'addCommand' command](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/addCommand.html).